# Bijective conformal maps from a torus to itself

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I would think of torus as follows: in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, consider two $\mathbb{R}$-independent vectors $\{v_1,v_2\}$. Then $v_1,v_2$ together with $0$ will determine a parallelogram, and this parallelogram (or vectors $v_1,v_2$) generate a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ as below:

[image]

The quotient of $\mathbb{C}$ by this lattice is a torus, which is a Riemann surface.

If $f\colon \mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a biholomorphic map which takes this lattice to itself, then it will induce a biholomorphic map from the torus to itself.

I want to know whether every biholomorphic map from torus to itself comes in this way? More precisely, I want to understand automorphisms of torus, and how they come from automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$?

(I am not well familiar with this area, I am trying to understand these points in ground level; please help me.)

Comment: Apart from these, there are also translations. Every automorphism is a composition of such maps. Do you know anything of covering maps?

Comment: yes, I know them from topology

Comment: Then a biholomoprhism $\mathbb C/\Gamma_1 \to \mathbb C/\Gamma_2$ will induces a holomorphism map between there universal covers, which are both $\mathbb C$.

Comment: OK. What about the relations between these maps (in the sense) if $f\colon \mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is biholomorphic preserving the lattice, and if $\tilde{f}$ is the corresponding induced biholomorphic map of torus, then how is the relation $f\mapsto \tilde{f}$? Is it one-one? onto?

Comment: It's not a one-one correspondence, but it's actually easier: You can describe all biholomorphism on $\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$.

Comment: It's onto, not one-to-one. If $f$ and $g$ differ by a translation by a lattice element, they induce the same map of the torus. And apart from the lattice-preserving biholomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$, any translation induces an automorphism of the torus.

Answer (score 2):

Summary of comments:

1. A biholomorphism $f:\mathbb C/\Gamma_1 \to \mathbb C/\Gamma_2$ will induces a holomorphism map $F$ between their universal covers, which are both $\mathbb C$. -- [John Ma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476182/bijective-conformal-maps-from-a-torus-to-itself#comment3005729_1476182)
2. The above map $F:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is also a biholomorphism, since $f^{-1}$ can also be lifted in the above way to some $G$ such that $F\circ G=\operatorname{id}$ on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.
3. Every biholomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ is $z\mapsto az+b$.
4. Some of the maps listed in 3 descend to the torus: namely, the automorphisms of the lattice, and translations (since all translations commute).
5. If two biholomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ differ by a translation by a lattice element, they induce the same map of the torus. And apart from the lattice-preserving biholomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$, any translation induces an automorphism of the torus. -- [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476182/bijective-conformal-maps-from-a-torus-to-itself#comment3005740_1476182)